# HOW TO query with linq GROUP BY multiple and SELECT

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-group

I already have the following code.
But i dont know whats wrong. Why cant i do the group by with the select?

Any idea?

thanks!

```
lstPendientes = await (from item in db.erProcesaReenvio
                       group item by new
                       {
                           item.iderRegistroCredito,
                           item.cuentaClabe,
                           item.nombreCliente,
                           item.idCtaProcesar,
                           item.No_Cuenta,
                           item.afiliado,
                           item.ImporteCobrar
                       } into g
                       select new {
                           prop1 = g.iderRegistroCredito,
                           prop2 = g.cuentaClabe
                       });
```

Comment: `prop1 = g.Key.iderRegistroCredito`...

Comment: SelectMany(). Should thjs be tagged VBA?

Comment: @KennethK.hey thanks, that works fine... post your answer.. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me

g.Key.iderRegistroCredito